# Array of size defined by not constant variable

Tags: c++, arrays

There is such code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int size;
  std::cin >> size;

  size = size + 1;
  int tab3[size];

  tab3[0] = 5;
  std::cout << tab3[0] << " " << sizeof(tab3) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
$ g++ prog.cpp -o prog -Wall -W 
$ ./prog
5
5 24
```

Why does this code even compile? Shouldn't be length of array a constant variable?

I used g++ version 4.4.5.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Variable-length arrays in C++ are available as an extension in GCC. Compiling with all warnings should have alerted you to that fact (include `-pedantic`).

Comment: +1, tho I had no idea `sizeof()` can also be non-constant. If I ever thought of using `sizeof()` on that I'd expect it to fail for some reason.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: again, as an extension... VLAs require a runtime `sizeof()`, so it's part of the C99 standard. It's just not a very C++-type of thing. Think about `decltype` and all this...

Comment: It is interesting though that there doesn't appear to exist *any* standardized method of allocating memory on the stack. We could handle object construction with placement-new, but it's just impossible in C++ to get a variable amount of raw memory on the stack.

Comment: Sure, I don't doubt it's a standard, it's just that I had no idea and never thought of it. Probably `alloca()` is not standardized, but it's pretty common, not?

Comment: There was a proposal to consider VLA's in C++ as well but the Standards committee dropped it because they considered the modifications to the type system for its support far outweighed the flexibility they would provide.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: I think `alloca()` exists only on *Linux*: "This function is not in POSIX.1-2001."

Comment: @Als: I don't mind not having VLAs. I can see how they don't fit the C++ type system. But what about a standard version of `alloca()`? I'd be happy to use it in my own allocator.

Comment: @KerrekSB — http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx — I don't think it's only on linux. And yes, that's what I meant by saying it's pretty common, not standardized.

Comment: @Kerrek: variable-sized stack allocation isn't very reputable. Uses of it pretty much all fall into two categories: (1) cases that could be handled using fixed-size allocation with a bit of extra bookkeeping; (2) potential causes of stack overflow. So while some people love it as a convenience, especially on systems where the stack magically extends itself almost indefinitely, the C++ committee members apparently aren't among them.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Arguably, Windows calls it `_alloca` with an underscore -- so much for any sort of uniformity! :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: What about a `std::vector` with a stack-allocator for extra locality? I think we need a deeper argument. Perhaps the problem is that you cannot **deallocate** those things...?

Comment: Here's something cute: Windows has a function that ["recovers from stackoverflow"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89f73td2.aspx)! (I've been trying for months to recover from StackOverflow...)

Comment: @Kerrek: what about it? What does it do when I write `stackvector v(1000000);`? What does it do when I write `void foo (stackvector &v) { v.reserve(1000000); }`? There's a longer and more nuanced argument of course, but the gist is that if you can't put a small upper bound on the size needed then it shouldn't be on the stack, and if you can put a small upper bound on the size, you can use an array or `std::array` of that size, plus some bookkeeping over how much is actually in use. Then it's a question of what you're willing to pay for the convenience of not doing that bookkeeping.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yeah, that sounds very reasonable... :-)

Answer (score 7):

It is a C99 feature, not a part of C++. They are commonly refered to as VLAs(Variable Length Arrays.

If you run `g++` with `-pedantic` it will be rejected.

See [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) for more info.

See also: [VLAs are evil](http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/04/07/c99s-vlas-are-evil/).

Answer (score 2):

GCC provide's VLA's or variable length arrays. A better practice is to create a pointer and use the `new` keyword to allocate space. VLA's are not available in MSVC, so the second option is better for cross platform code